# Does ARQ support SPARQL 1.1 Date and Time Functions?

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena, arq

I have been trying to do some formatting of date/time values to make them display as string literals in the result. I am using Jena ARQ from apache-jena-2.11.0 .

```sql
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX prov: <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?activity  ?agent ?time ?time (YEAR(?time) as ?year )   WHERE {
     ?activity prov:endedAtTime ?time ;
            prov:wasAssociatedWith ?agent .

}
```

ARQ reports the date time as

```
"2015-02-20T13:07:53+00:00:00"^^<xsd:dateTime>  to me.
```

This is how the property looks in RDF as a TTL  :

```
<http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#endedAtTime>
    "2014-08-04T15:35:09+01:00:00"^^<xsd:dateTime> ;
```

This was created with the following use of the Jena API:

```
resource.addProperty(PROVO.endedAtTime,
                model.createTypedLiteral(date, "xsd:dateTime"));
```

Maybe I am using the API wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Jena supports all the SPARQL 1.1 functions.

You have having problems because

```
"2015-01-07T15:22:53+00:00:00"^^<xsd:dateTime>
```

is not a datetime.

```
"2015-01-07T15:22:53+00:00:00"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>
```

or

```
"2015-01-07T15:22:53+00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime
```

`<xsd:dateTime>` is a completely different URI, URI scheme name "xsd".

Comment: Thanks Andy. Still a little unsure. I added some info about how I was using the Jena API. Is it my use that produces the wrong type for the property ?

Comment: Put the URI in when creating the literal: `model.createTypedLiteral(date, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime")`

Comment: @Interition Even more explicitly, the *string* "xsd:dateTime" is what you're passing to createTypedLiteral.  Jena expect an actual URI string.  Note that that the TTL include `"..."^^<xsd:dateTime>` with `<>` around the string `xsd:dateTime`.  When you use the actual URI, you'll get `"..."^^xsd:dateTime` with the proper URI.

Comment: Ah, I got it. Thanks. Is there a constant in the Jena API somewhere in the API for "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime" ? Seems a bit untidy to have to explicitly provide a string like that.

Comment: XSDDatatype for all your XSD needs.  Then you don't have to use the string form at all but use a typed constant.